# while inside while table another sql result work, but the parent not

Tags: php, while-loop

Hello Everybody I create While looping inside table to get room name and Room status available/Hours. I use While looping to get room name From table *ruangan_meeting*, AND room status from tx_meetingroom. the status is showing like looping, but the room name only show 1 result but in database

```
$sql2 = $koneksi->query("SELECT id, nama_room FROM ruang_meeting ORDER BY id ASC");
while ($data = $sql2->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<?php
    $id = $data['id'];
    $sql3 = $koneksi->query("SELECT * FROM tx_meetingroom WHERE id_ruang='$id'");
    while ($data2 = $sql3->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
        <td><?php echo $data['nama_room']; ?></td>
<?php
        if ($data2['start'] == "09:00:00") {
?>
            <td><a href='' class='btn btn-danger' disabled><i class='fa fa-ban'></i></a></td>
<?php
        }else{
            echo "<td><a href='' class='btn btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></a></td>";
        }
    }
}
```

the result:
[image]

Result in database is same like result, but the name not change:
[image]

Sorry for bad english

Comment: How many row are there in `ruang_meeting`

Comment: @RiggsFolly only 2 Ruang Meeting 1 AND Ruang Meeting 2